# Is there a way to wait after sending a signal to a process?

Tags: signals, go

When a signal (like os.Interrupt) is sent to a [process](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Signal), does the process waits until finish the process? Or, do we have to wait some time after?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Do you want to know whether [syscall.Kill](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Kill) blocks until the receiving application has finished ?

Comment: @dystroy sending signals does not block the sender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking if sending a signal will wait till the process is finished?

The answer is that it depends on the platform and the type of signal you send and what the process does with the signal. Some signals such as Kill can't be caught and will cause the process to terminate. Others don't do anything unless the process handles them. Still others will do something if the process doesn't handle them but the process can handle it if it want's to do something different. Until I know more about what you are asking this is the best answer I can give.

Comment: Kill will typically cause the process to terminate immediately but there are some cases where the process is stuck waiting for the filesystem (disk wait), so it may still be necessary to include some wait functionality in the calling code if it's necessary to block until the killed process is actually dead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait a moment (or a long time, maybe even forever, depending on how the signal is being handled).